# Local homomorphisms on a reduced local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that we have two local  rings $(R_1,\mathfrak{m}_1),(R_2,\mathfrak{m}_2)$  where $R_2$ is reduced and two local homomorphisms $\phi,\psi \colon R_1 \to R_2$ such that

$R_1\overset{\phi}{\to} R_2\overset{p}{\to} R_2/\mathfrak{m}_2$ and

$R_1\overset{\psi}{\to} R_2\overset{p}{\to} R_2/\mathfrak{m}_2$

agree, then is it true that $\phi=\psi$?

I can give more information about the problem in case it is an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) but i think that this is a purely algebraic fact.

My work so far is that for every $r\in R_1$ we have that $p(\phi(r)-\psi(r))\in \mathfrak{m}_2$ and that (trying to get a contradiction) if $\phi\neq\psi$ then there exists an $r\in R_1$ such that $\phi(r)-\psi(r)\neq0$ i.e $\phi(r)-\psi(r)\notin (0)=\sqrt{(0)}=\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\colon\text{prime in}\ R_2}\mathfrak{p}$ which implies that there exists a prime ideal in $R_2$, say $\mathfrak{q}$ such that $\phi(r)-\psi(r)\notin \mathfrak{q}$ but these facts do not seem to get me anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try $R_1=R_2=k[[x,y]]$, $\phi=Id$ and $\psi(x)=y,\psi(y)=x$.

Comment: Hmm, maybe somewhere I am wrong but i ended up trying to prove to this from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093421/equality-of-two-k-valued-points-for-reduced-k?rq=1) and with your counter example it seems that we would have a counter example in the proposition: "If $K$ and $X$ are schemes with $K$ reduced and $f,g$ morphisms from $K$ to $X$ then $f=g$ iff $f(x)\equiv g(x)$ for all $x\in K$" would not hold.

Comment: In the proposition you state, $x$ should be allowed to be all points $x\in K$, not just closed points.